# tried to login but fail with discord bot

Tags: bots, discord

so iv been trying to make my bot goes online but it gave me this error idk how to slove it tho

(node:4876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
    at WebSocketConnection.client.ws.connection.once.event (C:\Users\User\Desktop\JOJO bot\JOJO\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\ClientManager.js:48:41)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at WebSocketConnection.onClose (C:\Users\User\Desktop\JOJO bot\JOJO\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:390:10)
    at WebSocket.onClose (C:\Users\User\Desktop\JOJO bot\JOJO\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:124:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at _receiver.cleanup (C:\Users\User\Desktop\JOJO bot\JOJO\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:220:12)
    at Receiver.cleanup (C:\Users\User\Desktop\JOJO bot\JOJO\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:535:15)
    at WebSocket.finalize (C:\Users\User\Desktop\JOJO bot\JOJO\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:206:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
(node:4876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:4876) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide on how to ask questions on StackOverflow, as this is why you have reviewed downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token is probably invalid. Go back to the [developer portal](https://discordapp.com/developers) and check the token again, make sure to use it like `<Client>.login("token");`. Make sure you are using the token and not any other values, a bot token for discord starts with an `N` at the moment.